# async function as handler for socketio listener

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am trying to build in authentication to socketio websockets but running into an issue involving the setting of auth tokens. The problem boils down to the following: the function I'm using to get an up-to-date auth token is asynchronous, but it seems like providing an `async` function to the socketio listener for the `"reconnect_attempt"` event does not wait for the function to return before attempting the reconnect.

In short, this code

```js
socket.on("reconnect_attempt", async () => {
    const token = await getIdToken();
    socket.io.opts.query = { token };
});
```

does not actually set the socket's `query.token` before the reconnect request is sent to the server. As such, when a reconnect occurs after a token is expired, the expired token is sent while the new token is being fetched.

Is there any way to somehow configure socketio such that it waits for the listener's handler function to return before actually firing the reconnect request? If not, I imagine I'll have to just proactively refresh the token and store it somewhere in the app instead, but was curious if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the "reconnect_attempt" callback doesn't actually interrupt the request being made, but it just allows you to listen when it's trying. Instead, you could set your socketio connection to not auto-reconnect at all and subscribe to the disconnect event. Then, properly handle your token generation and initiate a new request from there.

```js
const socket = io({
  autoConnect: false
});

// socket.disconnected is a boolean to tell you if the connect is up or down
socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log(socket.disconnected); // false
});
```

https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#Event-%E2%80%98reconnect-attempt%E2%80%99-1

Answer (score 0):

I know two ways to achieve this. One is to turn your async function into a sync function.

```js
function wait_for(promise) {
  let ret, done;
  promise.then(r => {ret = r, done = true});
  while (!done) {}
  return ret
}

socket.on("reconnect_attempt", wait_for(
    (async () => {
      const token = await getIdToken();
      socket.io.opts.query = { token };
    })()
  )
);
```

Another way is to disable `reconnection`, and manually handle reconnection.

```
socket.reconnection(False);
socket.on("disconnect", async () => {
    const token = await getIdToken();
    socket.io.opts.query = { token };
    socket.open()
    // implement reconnect attempt limit, delay and such.
});
```